# Why qr-code with same mask, version and error correction has different dot distribution?

Tags: qr-code

In visualead.com qr-code generator there is option to choose how to fill the qr code.

There are two qr-codes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/izGH6.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0wX5.png

with same data that is encoded with same version=3, error correction level = M and mask=1. But then what makes this different dots distribution?

Comment: Effectively, I'm struggling with the same issue. Given the ISO/IEC 18004:2015 standard, two QR-Codes carrying the same information with the same version information should also have the same data blocks. I can't find any information in the standard, why they are different. Have you found anything? Please consider editing your question to make it more general; your example is correct, but the issue is not restricted to the generator you pointed out. I can reproduce the issue with different generators, different data contained, as well as different EC-levels, masking patterns and versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After multiple tests, I found out:
The QR-Code payload also depends on the data encoding. If you take UTF-8, the QR-Code will certainly look different than using Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1). If you set the QR-Code generator to encode the data the same way, the QR-Code will look the same.

So (for QR-Codes according to the standard) there needs to be:

- same Data
- same QR-Code version
- same Mask pattern
- same Error correction level
- same QR-Code encoding (Numeric, Alphanumeric, Byte, ...)
- **same Data encoding (independent from QR-Code settings)**

**Edit:** As mentioned by Mark Ambrazhevich in the comments of this answer, the QR-Code can be dependent of the following, too, keeping in mind that this violates the QR-Code standard (ISO/IEC 18004:2015): After the data has been inserted into the QR-Code, it has to be 'filled up' up to the limits. According to the standard, the placeholders `11101100` and `00010001` should be used alternating. But like Russ Cox discussed at https://research.swtch.com/qart:

> (post-terminator patterns) [...] Technically that's a violation of the spec, which prescribes a specific repeating 2-byte fill, but if all the readers you care about don't check the fill, then I agree it produces much nicer codes.

According to Kevin Baker on the same site, many commercial QR-Code-Readers do not check the post-terminator-data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry i dint see your comment before. Thats what i find out so far. Qr code contains blocks, first goes blocks contains data then blocks contains error correction. Like on this picture https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324235500/figure/fig2/AS:612231666470913@1522978812423/Arrangement-of-the-data-and-error-correction-codewords-within-a-Version-4-QR-code-with.png

Comment: Their quantity depends of error correction level, in my case there is M and 44 data blocks and 26 error corretion blocks. You can find this information on page 38 in ISO/IEC 18004. And when you fill data blocks you need to fill all blocks that is left after data filled by placeholders. Or Pad codewords wich is first 11101100 second 00010001, and then they repead untill all data blocks are filled. And there is where manipulation begins that affect this qr codes. Apprarently you can change this padding blocks since it dont affect the data. And qr code scanner doesnt notice it.

Comment: Eventually one good guy gave me a link to this https://research.swtch.com/qart where this manipulation explained in detales. Read the comments also there are also some information. Now i put ths topic away for a while, but still i intend to make qr code generator that minimize amount of dots in it, if you have same aim we can cooperate.

Comment: Right, I didn't think of that. That's a great page you mentioned. I'll update my answer to reflect that aspect, too. Thank you.
For your project: Keep in mind that minimising the dot-count is not quite the best thing to do for maximum capability. According to the standard, the amount of white should be similar to the amount of black parts.